# How to change Webform field value after a webform has been submitted

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform with a hidden field having a default value of No.  How do I change this value to Yes after a webform has been submitted using Rule? I'm using Drupal 7.x.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You should make a custom module, rather than using Rules.

Your module will implement the [hook_webform_submission_presave](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7), as shown also in webform.api.php inside webform directory.

Your function should look like this (well, this could be your entire .module file):

```
function mymodule_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {
  $component_id = 3; //that's your hidden field
  $submission->data[$component_id]['value'][0] = 'Yes';
}
```

Making a custom module is very easy, take a look [here](http://drupal.org/node/361112).